# How to use server-side pagination with ajax in bootstrap-table?

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination, bootstrap-table

I am looking for a way to implement the server-side (`paginationdata-side-pagination="server"`) for bootstrap-table with spring mvc. I want to retrieve data from the controller partially based on the pagination page id clicked by the user. I searched a lot but couldn't find any good resource on this through the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ajaxGet();
    });

    function ajaxGet(){
        var table_params = $('#docs_table').bootstrapTable({
            url: 'ajax/test_1/data?',
            queryParams: function (p) {
                return {
                    limit: p.limit,
                    offset: p.offset,
                    sort: p.sort,
                    order: p.order,
                    search: p.search,
                    'data[]': [other data],//for multi-select filter

                };
            }
        });
        $('#docs_table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
    }
```

You will receive parameters on server side as following:

***Parameters for paging***

1. Limit -- $_GET['offset']
2. Offset -- $_GET['offset']

***Parameters for data manipulation***

1. Search -- $_Get['search']
2. Sort -- $_Get['sort']
3. Order -- $_Get['order']

Reference:: [Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32298852/2037137)